What regions of Japan call this creature “okuri-inu” vs “okuri-ōkami”?
There are various legends in Japan of a creature that resembles a dog or wolf following travelers through the mountains at night. It typically stays at a distance, keeping pace but never approaching unless the traveler trips. Then the creature leaps on them and rips them apart. There are two ways to avoid this fate: Either not tripping or pretending the "trip" was in fact sitting down for a brief rest. Despite the risk, it can actually be a good companion since nothing else will bother a person being followed by this powerful creature, and in some versions they actively protect humans. Travelers who reach home safely can send the creature away by calling out, “Thank you for seeing me off,” which is where the “okuri” (meaning “sending-off” or “seeing off”) part of the name comes from. A final offering of food is also considered a good idea.
There are at least two names for the canine version of this creature: “okuri-inu” and “okuri-ōkami,” which mean “sending-off dog” and “sending-off wolf” respectively. “Yama-inu” or “mountain dog” is also a common variant. Many sources say the legends are found from Tohoku (far in the north) to Kyushu (the southernmost large island), with the terms implied to vary by region. However, they do not say which regions use which terms, except for the weasel version (okuri-itachi) that occurs on the Izu peninsula and in Saitama.
I have found a few sources that seem to mark regions using “dog” vs “wolf,” but I’m not sure how much to trust them. Wikipedia uses “okuri-ōkami” when describing legends in the Kantō and Kansai/Kinki regions plus Kōchi Prefecture in Shikoku. It then uses “okuri-inu” and “yama-inu” for two areas in Nagano Prefecture. One of those areas, Koumi, is specified to use “okuri-inu” for a version that protects people and “mukae-inu” for those that attack people. The source for this information is a Japanese book that as far as I can is not accessible in English, however, so I can’t confirm it. Based on my notes, the page also recently switched “okuri-inu” to “okuri-ōkami” for the Kantō/Kinki/Kōchi entry, so I’m suspicious of reading too much into it.
Meanwhile, an E-Budo forum includes an entry that talks of hearing “several tales of okuri-okami from around Nara.” Whether the author uses that term because it is connected to the region or because of personal preference is not clear. However, I have seen other information on wolf-worship in the Nara area, particularly Tamaki Shrine where they were considered divine messengers, so it’s possible they used “okuri ōkami” for this powerful creature that was only dangerous if you didn’t follow its rules.
I would appreciate any help in clearing up the question of what regions used “okuri-inu” vs “okuri-ōkami.” I’ll take any level of specificity, whether it’s narrowed down by town, prefecture, region, or even just general directions like north or southwest to help me ground this legend in its geographic context.

Very interesting question, and pertinent to me, who will be traveling to Nara anon. You might have better luck on Japanese.SE, if you don't have any hits here.

@cmw Good suggestion. If I end up re-posting over there and get a good answer, I'll make sure to include the link here for you and others in the community.

Thanks! I'm there, too, but I doubt most others would be. Hopefully you get your answer soon.

It looks like the modified (to focus on language) question I posted on Japanese.SE was not a good fit for that site, but I did get a suggestion of a Japanese yokai database that has allowed me to answer the question myself. I'll share my results and the database as an answer here once I have analyzed the data a bit more.

English-language sources on this creature are indeed sparse and vague when it comes to regional differences. However, there is a Japanese-language resource called the Kaii-Yōkai Denshō Database that does include regions for most entries. All text on the site is in Japanese, so it might not seem accessible for English-speakers. Most of the text can be copied-and-pasted, though. I opened up a tab with Google Translate and found I could navigate the entries fairly well. It does mistakenly read some locations as being written in Chinese, and it confuses details in the legend summaries (in one it had the wolf thanking the human for sending it off), but for the basic question of where the terms were used, it was workable.
I got the Japanese characters for okuri-inu (送り犬) from yokai.com and swapped the last character with the one for wolf to get okuri-ōkami (送り狼). Searching these terms, I found 14 entries for okuri-inu and 55 for okuri-ōkami. Looking through these results points to the following conclusions:
The creature is mainly a “dog” in the north and central parts of Japan. It is almost always a “wolf” in the southern areas.
The Chūbu region has the most “dog” entries and the Chūgoku region is the only one with exclusively “wolf” entries. The other regions contain some mixture or ambiguous entries that are tagged with “okuri-ōkami” but don’t actually use that word in the entries themselves.
Across 21 prefectures, the entries break down like this:

“Dog” only: Aichi and Shizuoka.
“Wolf” only: Fukui, Okayama, Shimane, Tottori, Tokyo, Shiga, Hyogo, Wakayama, and Nara.
Both “dog” and “wolf” used: Miyagi, Gifu, Ishikawa, Nagano, Niigata, and Yamanashi.
Mostly/all ambiguous entries: Mie, Saitama, Kanagawa, and Nagasaki (Kyushu).

The Kaii-Yōkai Denshō Database may not provide an exhaustive list of legends related to this creature. For instance, I could not find any entries that mentioned Kōchi Prefecture in Shikoku and Koumi town in Nagano like the Wikipedia article. It does reveal some useful patterns, however.
A few additional notes: In Nara, the entries were all from the Yoshino district, where Mt. Yoshino (considered a sacred mountain) and the Tamaki Shrine are located. Saitama has one entry with both terms and two ambiguous, which is not surprising since this area is where the weasel version of the legend occurs. The Nagasaki entry only mentions okuri-ōkami as a comparison with another supernatural canine, a white-haired dog.
